# How to run plain old java application on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to run a Java application on Android. It does not have a user interface and embeds Jetty as a servlet containr. It implements a web application that is normally accessed online by its users but I need to run this offline on Android tablets.

Is this at all possible? All I have been able to find is information on how to develop Android apps. I simply want the equivalent of `java -jar ...` and any information would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent of this in Android. Android uses a DVM instead of a normal JVM, which is based on [Apache Harmony](http://harmony.apache.org/).

You would in any case need to recompile the application since the DVM only executes Dalvik-Bytecode which is created from normal Java-Bytecode by the `dx`-tool shipped with the Android SDK.

Also, why do you need to run a Server-Application on a tablet device?

Comment: you may need server application on a mobile in some cases. For example what if you want to remotely access your tablet. You will look at option like VNC server on your tablets. Things like these will only be achieved if you have server running on your tablet

Comment: Remote-controlling an Android tablet... I don't know :D Remote-Controlling something *with* an Android Tablet makes more sense to me :D Also, I don't see why this shouldn't be possible by using Sockets.

Comment: heart of server application is a component which listens for the requests on a socket only. See this https://market.android.com/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&feature=search_result application for example

Comment: @saury this looks really cool, didn't know there was a Screen-capture api since Android 3.2 Reading the Source right now.

Comment: This is a web-application that allows users to interview people using a browser on a connected PC/laptop. We have an OFF-line option that runs the server on the local laptop on which they then browse to localhost. Now we need to replace the laptops with Android tablets so I need the server to run there. It is a plain Java application without UI (HTTP, File IO and Xalan for the XML stuff are the main dependencies).

Comment: @SilvioBierman you can try, but you'll need to recompile them in an Android project. If this works, there should be no problem.#

Answer (score 2):

You can't normally just run Java code, Android devices don't even have a Java VM. You have to recompile your application and convert it to dex, which is used by Dalvik VM. Whether it is easy to do so or not, depends, of course, on the APIs you use, since Android only has a subset of Java SE APIs.

Answer (score 0):

try GNURoot app (proot ptrace container) with debian Wheezy;
    apt-get update
    apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armel/jre/bin/java ...
(including long path)